# SQL Query for Parent-Child-Grandchild relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I would like to ask about any SQL query can doing a parent-child-grandchild relationship with level. Plus, I want the child is following their parent.

My table is like this

```
 ID  |ParentID|  ChildID    |Type
0048 |50199956|50856732(MB) |Got Child
0049 |50199956|50856711(GA) |Got Child
0050 |50199956|YUIOP-78-OP  |No Child

ID  |ParentID    |  ChildID    |Type
0051|50856732(MB)|NUYU-IO-OO   |Got Child
0052|50856732(MB)|5085675939   |No Child
0053|50856732(MB)|YRTOP-VG-34  |No Child

ID  |ParentID  |  ChildID  |Type
0122|NUYU-IO-OO|55466789   |No Child
0123|NUYU-IO-OO|34561277   |No Child
0124|NUYU-IO-OO|46796439   |No Child

ID  |ParentID    |  ChildID    |Type
0067 |50856711(GA)|IOP78I-UI-67 |No Child
```

Result I want:

```
ID   |ParentID    |ChildID      |Type
0048 |50199956    |50856732(MB) |Got Child
0049 |50856732(MB)|NUYU-IO-OO   |Got Child
0122 |NUYU-IO-OO  |55466789     |No Child
0123 |NUYU-IO-OO  |34561277     |No Child
0124 |NUYU-IO-OO  |46796439     |No Child
0050 |50856732(MB)|5085675939   |No Child
0051 |50856732(MB)|YRTOP-VG-34  |No Child
0067 |50199956    |50856711(GA) |Got Child
0052 |50856711(GA)|IOP78I-UI-67 |No Child
0053 |50199956    |YUIOP-78-OP  |No Child
```

### **EDITED**

Solved. Just use CTE recursion and add ID(varchar50)) with ID in child part then order by ID. Thanks to all who try to help me ^^

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by hierarchy path with recursive CTE

```
with h as(
    -- top level rows, no parent detected
    select cast(ChildID+'>' as varchar(max)) as path, * 
    from MyTable t1
    where not exists( select 1 from MyTable t2 where t1.ParentID = t2.ChildID)
    --
    union all
    select path + t.childID + '>', t.*
    from h
    join MyTable t on h.ChildID = t.ParentID
)
select * 
from h
order by path;
```

Comment: Seen like got some error
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "path" of recursive query "h"

Comment: Show your DDL please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the trick here is to know how to sort by generation.  In that case, for every row you'll have to check if they are the top generation, the middle or the bottom.

Since there're only three generations, we can just be lazy and join against itself two times to create a family ID.  `COALESCE` let's us default to the grandparent generation's ID, but if it doesn't exist (ie, this row is *not* a grandchild), then it'll use the parent's, but if *that* doesn't exist (ie, this row is not a child), then it'll use it's own ID (presuming this row is the grandparent).  By sorting by this ID, we group all members of a line together.  Then within that family ID, sort by the ID field which appears to be lower for earlier generations.

```
SELECT
a.id
,a.parentID
,a.childID
,COALESCE(c.ID, b.ID, a.ID) as sort_id    --if I have grandparents, sort by them, otherwise sort by my parents, otherwise myself
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b ON a.parentID = b.childID  --find my parents
LEFT JOIN table c ON b.parentID = c.childID  --find my grandparents
ORDER BY sort_id, a.id    --taking advantage of the fact that earlier generations have lower ID values
```

Comment: Actually it was not just 3 level, it has more, I just show some example at above.

Comment: Is it a known number of levels?

Comment: No. It may be 5 maybe more